# Round Robbin DNS and Windows Hosts file

Tags: windows, domain-name-system

I am trying to block all but 1 user from MSN chat (msn live or whatever it's called now).  My plan is to point the DNS to 127.0.0.1.  However one user has to have  it, I can edit the host file and put in the ip address to over ride the network DNS.  However MSN uses round robin DNS and I don't want to have it go down when they change servers. Does someone have a better idea on how to do this? or how to do round robin DNS in a host file?

Comment: What kind of firewall/proxy are you using?  Is this something that can be done at that level?

Comment: I know that host file editing can be a quick fix but it's a slippery slope towards other things being held together with bandaid fixes. If you have the resources aka business class equipment you should never have to resort to such methods.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could just leave DNS alone and block the IP's at the router.

Then use a DHCP reservation to give your one persion the same IP address each time, and allow that one to go through.

Way easier to manage (few changes in 1 place).  Little easier to troubleshoot in the future, plus a savvy user might just update his/her hosts file to get to MSN.

Not sure if you mean msn communicator/chat or the www.msn.com...  If it's the chat protocol, block the msn ports (do some searching) and you don't have to worry about IP's in the future...

Comment: blocking ports are not an option,  MSN chat can go out over port 80 http://support.microsoft.com/kb/927847 but I will  look at the firewall rules

Comment: Sniffing the traffic during login then blocking the IP it connects to seems to work.